# Where newly created workflow files stored?

Tags: workflow

If we create any list workflows or any other type .xsn file or .aspx files will create. Where these files are stored in content DB or in physical folder? If it is in physical folder then what is the path of the storage location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create workflows using SharePoint designer everything will be stored in the content database.

If yu create workflows using Visual Studio the files will be stored where you specify hat they should be stored inside the SharePointRoot Folder.

Comment: Does this include both 2010 and 2013 workflows?

Answer (score 1):

I agree above Answer and SharePoint designer workflows we can check in Designer having wfpub in that folder having all .xsn,xoml and rules files. each design workflow having a separate folder.

path is : Open Designer --> All files (left hand side) --> wfpub --> click and check

Comment: I cant find wfpub folder in the location suggested by you..

Comment: Open Designer --> All files (left hand side) -->_catalogs --> wfpub --> click and check

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have a subsite or not. But in general it's located in:
Sitename >> All Files >> Workflows >> YourWorkFlowName 
Each WF contains the following files:
workflowname.xoml
workflowname.xoml.rules
workflowname.xoml.wfconfig.xml
workflowname.xsn - which is your form for running the WF manually (if I remember correctly)